# EC2 instance does not have rights to download file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have application that downloads file from S3. I tested it on EC2 instance. When running interactivelly, app works fine.
I attach role to instance, remove ~/.aws folder and execute application. Download fails. SDK CPP log shows that metainfo service was queried and temporary access token was fetched. Next i see in log 404. Role assigned to EC2 instance has following inline policy

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "managebucketsid",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybuild"
        }
    ]
}
```

Same application is able to list bucket content but not to GetObject.
Aim is to run application as scheduled task, it means no AWS profile.

I also attached policy to bucket granting role full s3 access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the policy in your question is allowing actions in the bucket itself:

```yaml
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybuild"
```

and not "in it" or "on the objects inside it":

```yaml
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybuild/*"
```

in case you need both, you can update your policy to:

```yaml
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "managebucketsid",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybuild","arn:aws:s3:::mybuild/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

few examples of typical use cases for bucket policies:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-policies-s3.html

Comment: Many thanks. I ahve faced same issue few years back and I forgot :-( that separate permissions apply to bucket AND objects.
I run test again and file is downloaded.